# Can I stop headphone detection from triggering unpause/playback?

Tags: macbook-pro

I've got an Anker docking station that, after locking my macbook, will cause any paused audio (youtube, spotify, etc) to unpause. I've tracked this down to headphone jack detection (if i unplug/plug the speakers from the headphone jack on the docking station, it triggers the same).

I believe the macbook briefly loses connection to the docking station when sleeping after lock, and sometimes wakes up and reconnects, triggering the same thing that headphone unplug/plug does.

Is there a way to stop headphone plugin from triggering the "play/unpause" action?